# Sharepoint 2010 - BCS Content Type with Visual Studio 2010

Tags: visual-studio-2010, sharepoint-2010, bcs

I am making an external content type BCS project in visual studio. In the project I have a Linq to Sql class with an employee table in it and I have got an BCS model class (BDCM) in which I have one Entity named Employee, I have followed the below tutorial for your reference 
[Tutorial, please click here to see](http://fabiangwilliams.wordpress.com/2009/12/03/creating-a-sharepoint-2010-external-content-type-with-crud-methods-using-linq-and-a-sql-lob-system/)

When I am deploying and making a list in sharepoint site then I am getting this error

> Unable to display this Web Part. To troubleshoot the problem, open
>   this Web page in a Microsoft SharePoint Foundation-compatible HTML
>   editor such as Microsoft SharePoint Designer. If the problem persists,
>   contact your Web server administrator.
>
> Correlation ID:0b6e886b-a218-4658-82b2-23e82eb1fa5f

When I checked in sharepoint logs with the correlation ID it shows me this:

> External Lists: Using the default Filter settings for Finder
>   'ReadItem'in Entity 'Employee' of EntityNamespace
>   'SPCheck2010CSharp2.ExternalModel1'. This will likely result in
>   significant performance degradation.

Please help me find out the cause for this issue.

**-RHM**

Found this error also in the logs:

> Cannot find Property with name 'EmployeeID' on the parent object

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks for getting back to me but I resolved it, the typename on the Employee type descriptor under EmployeeList was not defined to the class "Employee" which is in the project as inside the DBML LINQ to SQL file.

Hope it helps someone out there !

Cheers :)

Answer (score 1):

My initial guess is that the two errors are related. First, the tutorial looks like "ReadItem" is a specific finder and not a finder method. So double-check that your ReadItem is a specific finder and not just a finder method. Then check your typedescriptor for each method and make sure that EmployeeID is set in the "Identifier" property of the type descriptor EmployeeID.

With BCS content types, it's almost always that you forgot to set up the type descriptor.

Comment: typedescriptor EmployeeID is set to Identifier "EmployeeID"

Comment: Have you tried putting a breakpoint in ReadItem and debugging it? Does it get into the method with a valid employeeID specified in the method parameter?